# application with zend framework only showing index.php not matter what url

Tags: php, linux, zend-framework

I'm running the zend framework 1.12. I'm unable to get anything other than the `index.php` file to load no matter what url I feed it. And when it loads the `index.php` it just shows the raw php code within that file. You can check it out here: `10.10.10.137/anything`. And you can literally put anything after the `/` and the same thing shows up.

Basically I cloned an app and have been trying to set it up on a different server, and I have never used Zend but I think that is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

> it just shows the raw php code within that file.

This probably means that your php installation is not working.

> I'm unable to get anything other than the index.php.

Review the tutorial for the Apache or Ngnix installation, you are missing mod_rewrite and / or the .htaccess file.

> You can check it out here: 10.10.10.137/anything.

I guess you know it is not possible to check a local network over the internet. If you really don´t know this yet, it is a good moment to go back to the books / tutorials.

Looks like your installation is missing some configuration, nothing else.